# Why must "Dispatchers.Main" be added to the root job of an implementation of an Activitys CoroutineScope?

Tags: android, kotlin, kotlin-coroutines

```
abstract class ScopedAppActivity: AppCompatActivity(), CoroutineScope {
    protected lateinit var job: Job
    override val coroutineContext: CoroutineContext 
        get() = job + Dispatchers.Main

    override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
        job = Job()

        launch(Dispatchers.Main) {
            try {
                delay(Long.MAX_VALUE)
            } catch (e: Exception) {
                // e will be a JobCancellationException if the activty is destroyed
            }
        }
    }

    override fun onDestroy() {
        super.onDestroy()
        job.cancel()
    } 
}
```

This example is copied from the [coroutine guide](https://github.com/Kotlin/kotlinx.coroutines/blob/master/ui/coroutines-guide-ui.md#structured-concurrency-lifecycle-and-coroutine-parent-child-hierarchy) and extended by the `launch(Dispatchers.Main)` coroutine. I don't understand why `+ Dispatchers.Main` in line 4 is needed. If I remove this part the `launch` coroutine will be cancelled anyways if the Activity is destroyed. So what is the reason for `Dispatchers.Main`? Why is `Dispatchers.IO` not added, too?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

When you wrote this:

```
launch(Dispatchers.Main) {
    try {
        delay(Long.MAX_VALUE)
    } catch (e: Exception) {
        // e will be a JobCancellationException if the activty is destroyed
    }
}
```

you may not have realized that `launch` is actually invoked with your `ScopedAppActivity` as the receiver. So you effectively wrote

```
this.launch(Dispatchers.Main) { ... }
```

`launch` is an extension function on `CoroutineScope` and it will use its `coroutineContext` as the starting point, combining it with whatever you specify in the parentheses. So, in your case, the effective context is

```
job + Dispatchers.Main + Dispatchers.Main
```

As you can imagine, this is equal to

```
job + Dispatchers.Main
```

so when you remove `Dispatchers.Main` from your `coroutineContext`, nothing changes.

> So what is the reason for Dispatchers.Main?

The advantage of providing `Dispatchers.Main` in `coroutineContext` is that you don't have to supply it every time, so you can just write

```
launch { ... }
```

and the block inside `launch` will stay on the GUI thread, which is the most natural way to use coroutines on Android and other GUI applications.

> Why is Dispatchers.IO not added, too?

Since that line is not about declaring all the dispatchers you'll use, but the default one, it doesn't make sense to provide more than one.

On another level, `CoroutineContext` isn't a list (which is kind of implied by the `+` operator), but a map. The `+` syntax works because each object you add declares its own map key, which `+` uses to put it into the context's internal map. So it's actually impossible to put two dispatchers into one `CoroutineContext`.

Comment: Could then `protected lateinit var job: Job` be removed and simply replaced by `override val coroutineContext: CoroutineContext = Job() + Dispatchers.Main` and a further replacement in `onDestroy` by `coroutineContext.cancel()`?

Comment: Yes, I believe this will work. The only thing it changes it that the `Job()` is there before `onCreate()` is called, so you can start a coroutine before the activity got to the `create` lifecycle point. I think it's more of a theoretical than a practical difference.

Answer (score 1):

Since Kotlin 1.3 you need a `CoroutineScope` to `launch` a new coroutine.
In your example you create a scope as `val` of the activity:

```
override val coroutineContext: CoroutineContext 
    get() = job + Dispatchers.Main
```

A coroutine scope consist of different parts, e.g. a dispatcher and a job.
The dispatcher is used to start the coroutine - select the thread - the job is used as the parent of the coroutines created from this scope.

If you specify another dispatcher at the invocation of the `launch` method, this dispatcher will override the standard dispatcher:

```
launch(Dispatchers.Main)
```

In your example the given `Dispatchers.Main` overrides the standard `Dispatchers.Main` - nothing happens.

Typically you define a standard dispatcher that is used in most places of your activity and only specify a special dispatcher if required.

Answer (score 1):

First i am not an expert in Corutines:

First question: *I don't understand why + Dispatchers.Main in line 4 is needed. If I remove this part the launch coroutine will be cancelled anyways if the Activity is destroyed. So what is the reason for Dispatchers.Main?*

U have a **Job** associatted with an **activity lifeCycle** and **Dispatchers.Main** wich is associatted with the **Android Main thread dispatcher and operating with UI objects**:

Looks pretty neat. If ur activity is destroying u will get ur job cancelled, and if ur main thread ends(example an exception occurs), u will get ur job cancelled.

2nd question: *Why is Dispatchers.IO not added, too?*

It doesnt make sense, to change to another Thread being on the Main-Thread of the application in this case, because the activity lives in the MainThread